# UWP, ControlChannelTrigger & the RtcRequestFactory class

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming, uwp

In the following MSDN article updated for UWP apps on Windows 10,
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/network-communications-in-the-background
we can read:
"Unlike other network transports, the HttpClient object cannot be directly passed into the UsingTransport method of the ControlChannelTrigger object. Instead, an HttpRequestMessage object must be specially constructed for use with the HttpClient object and the ControlChannelTrigger. The HttpRequestMessage object is created using the RtcRequestFactory.Create method."

When I use the RtcRequestFactory.Create method in a UWP app, I get the below error:
"System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
   at System.Net.Http.RtcRequestFactory.Create(HttpMethod method, Uri uri)"

When looking at https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dn600634(v=vs.110).aspx, it is mentioned that "The System.Net.Http.RtcRequestFactory class isn't supported in .NET Native".
My understanding is that UWP app has to use .NET Native.

So it looks like using RtcRequestFactory is not an option for a UWP app.
What are the alternatives to do network communications in the background?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to use **ControlChannelTrigger** with **HttpClient** to implement network communications in the background.

There are two **HttpClient** APIs for implementing the HTTP client role in a managed UWP app: [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.httpclient). Based on [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781239.aspx), it says that the [System.Net.Http](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http(VS.110).aspx) namespace might not be available in future versions of Windows for use by Windows Store apps. Starting with Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2, please use [Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.httpclient) in the [Windows.Web.Http](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.aspx) namespace.

To use ControlChannelTrigger with [Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.httpclient), an HttpRequestMessage object is also needed, but it can be created without **RtcRequestFactory.Create** method.

You can find the implementation in the [official sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ControlChannelTrigger-HTTP-9d7a6b3d) (project HttpClientTransportHelper -> Class CommunicationModule -> Method SetUpHttpRequestAndSendToHttpServer and SendHttpRequest) which shows how to use the ControlChannelTrigger class with the HttpClient in the new **Windows.Web.Http** namespace. Note: It is Windows 8.1 sample, but it can be easily reused in UWP.

```
HttpRequestMessage httpRequest= new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, serverUri);
channel.UsingTransport(httpRequest);
```